# ASP.net menu control expand on mouse click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, menu

I have an ASP.NET menu control and I've ran into something about it that I've never been asked before.  I was hoping someone might know. Some searching online hasn't turned up much on this so I wanted to ask the community here for help.

Can the ASP.NET menu control be code so that, on a multi-tier menu, it will only expand on a mouse-click, not on hover?

This sounds like a job for javascript to me but I wanted to ask for advice before I wrestled with this any further.

Comment: is it mandatory to use ASP.NET menu control

Comment: So far yes.  But I know that management is open to other solutions (even purchasing 3rd party controls).  I just wanted to see if there was a feasible way to do this in-house.

Comment: why 3rd party controls , Google jquery + css multi-level menu you'll found plenty of solutions

Comment: Well we went with the ASP.NET menu control because to be honest, it was most familiar.  We have a requirement that the menu has to be completely data-driven.  So depending on what customer is logged in, they see a different menu structure (different products to choose from etc).  That is all in our database.  I was assuming that sticking with a control would be best.  However, maybe we have to look at rolling our own solution here.

Comment: maybe it can help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1138755.aspx

Comment: No dice on any of that.  We are in fact using the sitemap to fill the control so we have the NavigateURL property set.  Perhaps I'll have to look into rolling my own solution here.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the ASP.NET menu control (at least not in my siutation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up following advice in the comments from my original question.  I did not see a way to mark a comment as the answer so I'm answering here.

The advice from Siz S was sound (although I Bing'd it instead of Googling, lol)  I went with SuperFish for my menu and transformed my xml data into an unordered list. So far this is working great and got the users just what they were looking for.  Plus it seems faster than the ASP.NET menu control